# RecyclerView + ScrollView + CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-layout, android-scrollview, coordinator-layout

Проблема такая: 
имеется разметка с coordinatorLayout, в ней есть AppBarLayout и ScrollView, в ScrollView есть RecyclerView горизонтальный + остальные view.

Если скролить за обычные view, то всё хорошо, тулбар поднимается как и должен.

А если скролить за recyclerView, то scrollView уходит под AppBarLayout, а тот в свою очередь стоит на месте
С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: с конфликтом скроллящихся виджетов. Попробуйте использовать [`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

Comment: забыл написать, что его я тоже уже использовал, всё так же

Answer (score 3):

Вернитесь к использованию `NestedScrollView`. С обычным ничего не добьетесь.

Затем попробуйте Вашему `RecyclerView` установить `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`.